# php mysql query combination

Tags: php, mysql

I first search all questions info. from "question" table including title, content, user etc.
the Code:

```
$sql  = "select * FROM question where id>0 ORDER BY id ASC";  
    $result1 = mysql_query($sql);
    $res=Array();
```

And then I want to search the user's point from "user" table. So I must search point for each user in each row from the result1 
The Code:

```
while($rows=mysql_fetch_assoc($result1))
    {
        $res[]=$rows;
        $user = $rows['user'];
        $sql2 = "select point from user where name='$user'";
        $result2 = mysql_query($sql2);  
    }
```

My problem is how to combine all the users' point(result2) with the questions info.(result1) together so that I can return a json for each row.

Comment: mysql is deprecated, please consider using mysqli APIs. Might help to have sample input and output, but I think the key is that right now you overwrite $result2 with each iteration of the while loop. I believe you want $result2 to be an array and you append (push) each new result to the array.

Comment: hint: consider using JOIN statements instead.

Comment: `select question.*,user.point FROM question
left join user
on user.user = question.user`

Comment: Oh my god. Thanks to all people who answered this question. I am a newbie in mysql and php. I learnt the JOIN statement and solved my problem. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use left join, as my understanding this work for you

```
$sql  = "SELECT q.*, u.point AS point FROM question AS q LEFT JOIN user AS u ON q.user = u.name WHERE q.id > 0 ORDER BY q.id ASC";  
$result = mysql_query($sql);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's better go with the joins here i am giving you the query.i hope it may helps you

```
select * from question q,user u where q.id>0 ORDER BY id ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

try something like this:*using left join*

```
select question.*,user.point FROM question left join user on user.name= question.name where id>0 ORDER BY id ASC
```